# Shopping List program

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, email

This is a shopping list program made in Python 3 and it will send the list by email. I am not very experienced but I consider this program as a starting point to what I will do next.

```
import smtplib

from email.message import EmailMessage

from getpass import getpass

name = str(input("Name: "))
email = str(input("Email: "))
password = str(getpass("Password: "))
recipient = str(input("Recipient's email: "))

while True:
    try:
        productsnm = int(input(f"Hi, {name}!\nHow many products do you want to add to the shopping list? " ))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Please input a number.")
    else:
        break

products = []
quantities = []

for x in range(int(productsnm)):

    product = str(input("Input the product name: "))

    while True:
        try:
            quantity = int(input("Input the product quantity: "))
        except ValueError:
            print ("Please input a number.")
        else:
            break

    products.append(product)
    quantities.append(quantity)

print ("\nThese products have been added to the shopping list:")

for x, y in zip(products, quantities):
    print (f'{x} x {y}')

gmail_user = email 
gmail_password = password

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = "Shopping List"
msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = [recipient]
message = ""
for i in range(max(len(products), len(quantities))):
    message = message + str(products[i]) + " x " + str(quantities[i]) + "\n"
msg.set_content(message)

try:
    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    s.ehlo()
    s.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    s.send_message(msg)
    s.quit()

    print ("\nThe email has been sent.")

except:  
    print ("\nAn error occurred.")

print ("\nHave a nice day!")

exit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions, functions, functions. They make your life a lot easier, because they allow you to give a clear name to things and even add a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to it to add even more description of what the function does. It also means that instead of having to read a whole block of code it is usually enough to read the name of the function to know what is happening (if it is a good name, of course, [one of the harder problems in computer science](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)).

Now, let's get to defining some functions. Ideally each function is responsible for one thing, and one thing only (the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

First, a function that asks for user input, with a given message and a type:

```
def get_user_input(message, type=str):
    """Ask the user for input using `message`.
    Enforce that the input is castable to `type` and cast it.
    """
    while True:
        try:
            return type(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print (f"Please input a {type}.")
```

Note that in your case calling `str` on `input` is not necessary in Python 3, since it always returns a `str`. But here we need it to allow accepting arbitrary types.

Next, I would keep your products and quantities as a dictionary of `product_name: quantity` key-value pairs. This even allows you to aggregate items if I enter an item multiple times:

```
def add_item(shopping_list):
    """Add an item to the shopping list.
    If the item already exists in the list, add the quantity to it.
    """
    name = get_user_input("Input the product name: ")
    quantity = get_user_input("Input the product quantity: ", int)
    shopping_list[name] += quantity
```

This would normally lead to a `KeyError` whenever `name` is not already in the dictionary, but will work out fine if `items` is a [`collections.defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Printing the shopping list is also easy:

```
def print_list(shopping_list):
    for name, quantity in shopping_list.items():
        print(name, "x", quantity)
```

And emailing the list to someone should also be a function:

```
def email_to(shopping_list, from_email, password, *recipients):
    email = EmailMessage()
    email['Subject'] = "Shopping List"
    email['From'] = from_email
    email['To'] = recipients
    message = "\n".join(f"{name} x {quantity}" for name, quantity in shopping_list.items())
    email.set_content(message)

    try:
        s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        s.ehlo()
        s.login(from_user, password)
        s.send_message(email)
        s.quit()
        print ("\nThe email has been sent.")
    except Exception as e:  
        print ("\nAn error occurred:", e)
```

This function could probably be split up further to allow e.g. using a different provider than GMail.

Note that catching all exceptions with a bare `except` means also e.g. the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which you usually don't want to do. Instead at least catch only `Exception` and be more specific if you can. You should also print to the user *which* exception occurred, for which you can use the `as` keyword.

Then your main calling code becomes:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from getpass import getpass
from collections import defaultdict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = input("Name: ")
    n = get_user_input(f"Hi, {name}!\nHow many products do you want to add to the shopping list? ", int)
    shopping_list = defaultdict(int)
    for _ in range(n):
        add_item(shopping_list)
    print_list(shopping_list)

    email = input("Email: ")
    password = getpass("Password: ")
    recipient = input("Recipient's email: ")
    email_to(shopping_list, email, password, recipient)
```

---

As you can see, almost all functions actually take `shopping_list` as a first argument. So you could also make this into a class:

```
class ShoppingList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = defaultdict(int)

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(f"{name} x {quantity}" for name, quantity in self.items.items())

    def add_item(self, name, quantity):
        self.items[name] += quantity

    def email_to(self, from_email, password, *recipients):
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = input("Name: ")
    n = get_user_input(f"Hi, {name}!\nHow many products do you want to add to the shopping list? ", int)
    shopping_list = ShoppingList()
    for _ in range(n):
        name = get_user_input("Input the product name: ")
        quantity = get_user_input("Input the product quantity: ", int)
        shopping_list.add_item(name, quantity)
    print(shopping_list)

    email = input("Email: ")
    password = getpass("Password: ")
    recipient = input("Recipient's email: ")
    shopping_list.email_to(email, password, recipient)
```

Comment: So which is better? With or without the class?

Comment: @DavidAndrei: I think here the version with the class is better, because it bundles up all things that manipulate the shopping list (which makes it a perfect candidate to be an object). I did not write the answer with just the class, though, because I wanted to have two different knowledge steps up from your code, the first being to organize the code use functions, the second being OOP.

Comment: When I try to do the class version it throws me this error: KeyError: '__main__.ShoppingList' and I think it is because of email.set_content. Can you tell me what should I put in email.set_content please?

Comment: @DavidAndrei Just replace `shopping_list.items()` with `self.items.items()`. Otherwise it should be exactly the same as the first `email_to`.

Comment: I still get the same error. Here is my entire code: https://pastebin.com/SXu6F7zz

Comment: Fixed, I had to make message = str(self)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Code Review. While your script works as is, it is a good practice to setup and split parts of code into functions, and place the entry point inside [the `if __name__` wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

---

You have an extra conversion to `int` for `productsnm` (which could be better named `product_count`).

---

Since each product is associated with its own quantity, say hello to a [`namedtuple`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.7/library/collections#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple
Product = namedtuple('Product', ['name', 'quantity'])
# inside the for-loop:
    products.append(Product(name=product_name, quantity=quantity))
```

You wont need the string manipulation, or the loop. Just printing out the `products` list should give you something like

```
[Product(name='n0', quantity=0), Product(name='n1', quantity=1), Product(name='n2', quantity=32)]
```

Each element of the list now has `name` and `quantity` as its property as well.

---

You can have multiple functions as follows:

- `gather_products_list` which returns a list of `N` products.
- `generate_email_body` to process the `products` provided to the function and generating the raw email body.
- `send_email` which accepts the aforementioned raw body, and sends it via the provider of choice.
- `get_integer` which repeatedly asks the user to input an integer value. This function could accept an optional `prompt` message as well as an `error` message!